# How do I build a project template for multi-platform in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, templates

I know how to build a template for iOS. Key to doing this is creating a .xctemplate file in directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates. My library includes a key Ancestors and the value here is com.apple.dt.unit.coreDataCocoaTouchApplication
I've done this but my template is only made available for iOS. I can't see why unless this is determined by the above value. How can I make my template multiple-platform?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
The Multiplatform project template I needed is in:

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/MultiPlatform/Application/App.xctemplate**